# Updating multiple rows using select PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Below is the code where I am trying to change the values of one column in multiple rows but I am a little bit stuck.

**File 1**:

```
<form name="update-location" method="post" action="recibos_location_update.php">

<div align="right"><button type="submit">Actualizar Estado</button></div>
<hr />

<ul>
    <?php
        $get_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recibos ORDER BY id DESC");
        while ($logs = mysql_fetch_array($get_logs)){

        $serial = $logs['serial'];
        $check = $logs['location'];
        $problem = $logs['problem'];
    ?>

    <li class="<?php 
        if ($check == $location1){echo 'recibos-container-shop-li';}
        if ($check == $location2){echo 'recibos-container-haji-li';}
        if ($check == $location3){echo 'recibos-container-return-li';} ?>">

        <?php echo $serial . " | " . $logs['model'] . " | " . $problem; ?>

        <div align="right">
            <?php
                if ($check != 'Returned'){
            ?>
                <input type="hidden"  name="serial[]" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>" />
                <select name="location">
                    <option <?php if ($check == $location1){echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $location1; ?>" style="background: #fff8bf;">Mobils Calfont</option>
                    <option <?php if ($check == $location2){echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $location2; ?>" style="background: #ffc1bf;">Haji Jorda</option>
                    <option <?php if ($check == $location3){echo 'selected';} ?> value="<?php echo $location3; ?>"style="background: #ecffbf;">Devuelto</option>
                </select>
            <?php
            }
            else {
                echo "<i><font color='#5e8029'>Devuelto</font></i>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**File 2**

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
include "links.php";


foreach($_POST["serial"] as $serial){

    $location = $_POST['location'];
    echo $location . " " . $serial . "<br>";
}
mysql_query("UPDATE recibos SET location='$location' WHERE serial='$serial'");

//header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

?>

and the output I am getting is:

```
Haji 900005
Haji 900004
Haji 900002
```

But for all 3 output lines, it should give different names as names in 3 select boxes were different.

What I need is for the process form to update every row with what value is contained in select box options.

Comment: Usually when one's trying to change something, their code will have an `UPDATE` statement. I do not see one here.

Comment: oops, i just saw my statement above about updating the rows, well i update my question.. thanks for the point out. well, right now i am only printing the taken values as is to see if the code is working fine or not... so if it is not printing the names correctly, it will not write the names correctly in colums in database rows.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to red card you and suggest you read up on [SQL injection issues](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because what you're doing here is like picking up a needle out of the gutter and stabbing it in your arm. Not safe.

Comment: well i didnt see that coming... red carding... all i need is a solution... and well.. i am vulnerable to that.. not you... so plz act a little grown up :/

Comment: @digitiZer: same goes to you. a serious fundamental security flaw in your code has been pointed out, and your response has been to stick your fingers in your ears and go "la la la la".

Comment: well **thanks** because i am aware of that and i am not having this as some banking page. This is just a practice code i am doing offline on xampp.. now... i havent put this code for you guys to point out irrelevant flaws in this case. and i am not going "la la la" ... i did read that MOM STUDENT brilliant conversation Mr. tadman just highly suggested..... ..lolz.... "la la la".... are you serious?

Comment: and what made me like.... "what the...." he red carded me like he had paid me to write him some code or something... :/ guys please

Comment: This super casual attitude towards SQL escaping is what gives PHP and its developers a bad name. Please, do not think of it as an academic concern. Do take it seriously. The internet is not all rainbows and kittens. It has a large population of people that can and will ruin your life if you leave yourself open like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<select name="location[]">
```

php

```
foreach($_POST["serial"] as $k=> $serial){

    $location = $_POST['location'][$k];
    mysql_query("UPDATE recibos SET location='$location' WHERE serial='$serial'");
}
```

Comment: thanks great sir. you really saved the day. worked like a charm :D. **Also** wanted to request a little favor if you could post some link to understand this coding as i wanted to understand these expressions in future if i want to do something same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST["serial"] as $serial){

    $location = $_POST['location'];
    echo $location . " " . $serial . "<br>";
    mysql_query("UPDATE recibos SET location='$location' WHERE serial='$serial'");//update
}
//    mysql_query("UPDATE recibos SET location='$location' WHERE serial='$serial'");
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is working with outputing the location with lowest serial number and put the same location in all columns of rows. Same as was working with my code above.